# What are flight check operations?

Tags: airport, usa, faa, airport-operations

[KDCA/DCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Reagan_Washington_National_Airport) is currently experiencing delays in both arriving and departing aircraft, and several sites list variations of "Flight check operations" as the reason.

The [FAA itself](https://www.fly.faa.gov/flyfaa/flyfaaindex.jsp?ARPT=DCA&p=0) provides the following status for DCA (which I'm guessing is where all the other sites pull from):

> Due to OTHER / FLIGHT CHECK, there is a Traffic Management Program in
> effect for traffic arriving Ronald Reagan Washington National Airport,
> Washington, DC (DCA). This is causing some arriving flights to be
> delayed an average of 20 minutes. To see if you may be affected,
> select your departure airport and check "Delays by Destination".

At a commercial airport, what is a Flight Check / what are flight check operations? Why would they be implemented?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aircraft that fly and check the navigational aids for calibration/maintenance/certification purposes. Their presence reduces the airspace capacity, hence the delay you read about.

> **26. Flight Inspection/"Flight Check" Aircraft in Terminal Areas**
>
> **26.1** "Flight Check" is a call sign used to alert pilots and air traffic controllers when an FAA aircraft is engaged in flight inspection/certification of NAVAIDs and flight procedures. Flight check aircraft fly preplanned high/low altitude flight patterns such as grids, orbits, DME arcs, and tracks, including low passes along the full length of the runway to verify NAVAID performance.
>
> **26.2** Pilots should be especially watchful and avoid the flight paths of any aircraft using the call sign "Flight Check." These flights will normally receive **special handling from ATC.** Pilot patience and cooperation in allowing uninterrupted recordings can significantly help expedite flight inspections, minimize costly, repetitive runs, and reduce the burden on the U.S. taxpayer.
>
> — US AIP [ENR 1. GENERAL RULES AND PROCEDURES](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aip_html/part2_enr_section_1.1.html)

And from JO 7110.65, simply doing those procedures at say 3 AM when commercial traffic is light may not be possible:

> **[9-1-3](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap9_section_1.html#NhIf0JACK). FLIGHT CHECK AIRCRAFT** [...] *Certain flight inspection maneuvers require operations in close proximity to the surface. These maneuvers can only be performed during **daylight** visual meteorological conditions.* [...]

---

*Special thanks to @randomhead for the flight tracking:*

By using Flightradar24's playback feature beginning at approximately 1400Z, a Super King Air 300 can be seen performing the flight check:

> [image: Flightradar24]

The airport was running in a north flow (departing and arriving using runway 01), and at approximately 1510Z the aircraft is seen flying what appears to be the *RNAV (RNP) RWY 15* approach—the opposite direction to the rest of the traffic using the airport, necessitating delays.

*The registration was blocked on Flightradar24, on the other hand [ADS-B Exchange](https://www.adsbexchange.com/), which does not censor traffic, does not have a playback feature when the registration is not known.*

---

Related posts and further reading:

- [What is flight inspection, as provided by Cobham Aviation Services?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35341/14897)
- [How often is ILS accuracy checked?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/74043/14897)
- [8240.41C - Flight Inspection/ Air Traffic On-Site Coordination Requirements](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/14504)
- Pilot/Controller Glossary: [FLIGHT CHECK](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/pcg_html/glossary-f.html#%24FLIGHT%20CHECK)
- For how ATC prioritizes the traffic, see 7110.65 § [2-1-4](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_1.html#OTJ2b2JACK)

Comment: no problem, I tend to be rather verbose. I thought the mention of *relarive* priority for FLC (13/17) might be of interest, but it's not essential.

Comment: @randomhead: I didn't realize you were mentioning the ranking. I readded it in the further reading, because 1–12 are not non-emergency scheduled traffic :D